# Own counter starts at 3 in tabularx environment

Tags: counters, tabularx

the following example shows that the self defined counter in the `tabularx` environment does not start with "1". Can't figure out how to define the command to always start with "1". Ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\makeatletter\newcommand*{%
\CreateCounterIfNotExists}[1]{\begingroup%
\@ifundefined{c@#1}{\newcounter{#1}}{}%
\endgroup}\makeatother

\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\requirement[3]{%
\CreateCounterIfNotExists{my#1}%
\sdef{themy#1}{#1\arabic{my#1}}%
\refstepcounter{my#1}%
\label{#2} #1\arabic{my#1}: #3%
}

\begin{document}
\requirement{A}{req:foo:a}{Starts with 1}
\requirement{A}{req:foo:b}{continues with 2}
\requirement{B}{req:hop:a}{Starts with 1}
\requirement{B}{req:hop:b}{continues with 2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    \caption{Requirements}\\
    \label{tbl:reqs}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Area}& \textbf{Description}  \\\midrule
    \requirement{C}{req:bar:A}{Starts with 3}
    \requirement{C}{req:bar:B}{Continues with 4}
       & 
    This should start with C1    \\\midrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `cleveref` should be the last package, in most cases, but this is not the cause of your problems. Why do you think, it should start with 1 using `tabularx`?

Comment: By the way, you could use the `\ifltxcounter` from `etoolbox` to test for the counter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't define counters while `tabularx` does its job.

A solution may be to define the one you need in a `tabularx` beforehand, or do it in a delayed fashion using the `.aux` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\requirement[3]{%
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\CreateCounter{#1}}%
  \@ifundefined{c@my#1}
    {#1??: #3}
    {\refstepcounter{my#1}\label{#2}#1\arabic{my#1}: #3}%
}
\newcommand{\CreateCounter}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@my#1}
    {\newcounter{my#1}\global\@namedef{themy#1}{#1\arabic{my#1}}}
    {}%
}
\AtEndDocument{\let\CreateCounter\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
{\requirement{A}{req:foo:a}{Starts with 1}}
\requirement{A}{req:foo:b}{continues with 2}
\requirement{B}{req:hop:a}{Starts with 1}
\requirement{B}{req:hop:b}{continues with 2}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
\caption{Requirements}\label{tbl:reqs}\\
\toprule
\textbf{Area}& \textbf{Description}  \\
\midrule
\requirement{C}{req:bar:A}{Starts with 1}
\requirement{C}{req:bar:B}{Continues with 2} & This should start with C1 \\
\midrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first time `\requirement{X}` is used, the number won't be generated, but it will at the next LaTeX run.

Comment: Splendid. I like this solution most since it doesn't require to define a list of envisioned/used requirements in the preamble.

Comment: One more thing, if I add the line ```This ref should be named "C1": \ref{req:bar:A}. But it's called "1".``` to the end of your example it shows that the references have no prefix anymore.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, `\global` missing.

Answer (score 3):

You should almost never declare a counter within a macro, it should be declared once in the preamble and just used. then `tabularx` would know about it and preserve its value when doing trial width settings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}

\newcounter{myA}\renewcommand\themyA{A\arabic{myA}}
\newcounter{myB}\renewcommand\themyB{B\arabic{myB}}
\newcounter{myC}\renewcommand\themyC{C\arabic{myC}}



\newcommand\requirement[3]{%
\refstepcounter{my#1}%
\label{#2}#1\arabic{my#1}: #3%
}

\begin{document}
\requirement{A}{req:foo:a}{Starts with 1}
\requirement{A}{req:foo:b}{continues with 2}
\requirement{B}{req:hop:a}{Starts with 1}
\requirement{B}{req:hop:b}{continues with 2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    \caption{Requirements}\\
    \label{tbl:reqs}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Area}& \textbf{Description}  \\\midrule
    \requirement{C}{req:bar:A}{Starts with 3}
    \requirement{C}{req:bar:B}{Continues with 4}
       & 
    This should start with C1    \\\midrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Very clean and compact. However, defining the counters in the header is not as handy as the solution provided by egreg, since you've to know beforehand which counters to use the in document.

Answer (score 2):

As in the solutions by David Carlisle and egreg mentioned: counters should not be defined `on-the-fly`.

I used a similar approach as David Carlisle, providing a `\NewDocumentCounter`, `\DeclareRequirement`, `DeclareRequirements` commands which can be used in preamble only, to prevent accidental usage.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewDocumentCounter}{m}{%
  \ifltxcounter{#1}{%
  }{%
    \typeout{Creating counter #1}
    \newcounter{#1}%
  } 
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareRequirement}{m}{%
  \NewDocumentCounter{my#1}%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname themy#1\endcsname{#1\arabic{my#1}}
}%

    \listgadd\reqlist{}


\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareRequirements}{+m}{%
  \forcsvlist{\listgadd\reqlist}{#1}
  \forlistloop{\DeclareRequirement}{\reqlist}
}%



\makeatletter
\@onlypreamble{\NewDocumentCounter}
\@onlypreamble{\DeclareRequirement}
\@onlypreamble{\DeclareRequirements}
\makeatother




\DeclareRequirements{A,B,C} % Declare all requirement counters in a row ... 


\newcommand\requirement[3]{%
  \refstepcounter{my#1}%
  \label{#2} #1\arabic{my#1}: #3%
}

\begin{document}
\requirement{A}{req:foo:a}{Starts with 1}
\requirement{A}{req:foo:b}{continues with 2}
\requirement{B}{req:hop:a}{Starts with 1}
\requirement{B}{req:hop:b}{continues with 2}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
    \caption{Requirements}\\
    \label{tbl:reqs}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Area}& \textbf{Description}  \\\midrule
    \requirement{C}{req:bar:A}{Starts with 3 no longer} %\themyC
    \requirement{C}{req:bar:B}{Continues with 4 no longer} %\themyC
    & 
    This should start with C1    \\\midrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, tested and it works. But declaring the possible requirements/counters in the preamble was something I wanted to avoid.